# Susy 2 and Media Queries

Tags: breakpoints, susy

I need some help about setting breakpoints for my theme.
Basically it's some simple : mobile; tablet and desktop.
But the issue come with landscape orientation and device resolution.
Actually this is my variables and a code example:

```
$mobile   :  500px;
$tablet   :  700px;
$desktop  :  950px;// sortie=>> min-width: 950px
/////////////*******
@include susy-breakpoint ($tablet){
     max-width: container($tabletcol);
  }
  @include susy-breakpoint ($desktop){
      max-width: container($desktopcol);
  }
```

Have you some efficient code that you are using on applications ?

thanks

EDIT: found this that help but i need help to set it good
http://breakpoint-sass.com/

```
$tabletlandscape: (min-height 767px) (orientation landscape);//pour orientation paysage
```

Comment: i think i have a grid issue because debug give me : 

`/var/www/sandboxd6/sites/all/themes/starter-susy2-d6/sass/layout/_layout.scss:37 DEBUG: 4
/var/www/sandboxd6/sites/all/themes/starter-susy2-d6/sass/layout/_layout.scss:92 DEBUG: 4
/var/www/sandboxd6/sites/all/themes/starter-susy2-d6/sass/layout/_layout.scss:132 DEBUG: 4` instead different column value, isn't it ? different lines are my breakpoint : mobile, tablet and desktop

Comment: still there , breakpoints not applied by browser (FF,chrome) at 950px min-width on screen with 1900px width..